# The action of real special linear group on the complex plane

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, linear-groups

Let $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\curvearrowright \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ where $Az=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$

Show that if $z=x+iy$ with $y>0$ (has positive imaginary part) then $Az$ does too.

Then, considering this same action, show that the orbit of 1 is $ R \cup\infty$

---

**Progress** So far I have tried plugging it in, attempting to work around with some clever "1's" (e.g. $i/i$) to change the form. With $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ we know that $ad-bc=1$ so I've been attempting to see if that has anything to do with the answer as well.

Comment: What have you tried?  I would just substitute $z = x + iy$ into your formula for $Az$ and figure out its imaginary part.

Comment: So far I have tried plugging it in, attempting to work around with some clever "1's" (e.g. $i/i$) to change the form. With $SL_2(R)$ we know that $ad-bc=1$ so I've been attempting to see if that has anything to do with the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$ \frac{a(x+iy)+b}{c(x+iy)+d} = \frac{(ax+b)+iay}{(cx+d)+icy} $$
Multiplying by $1$,
$$ \frac{(ax+b)(cx+d-icy)+iay(cx+d-icy)}{(cx+d)^2+(cy)^2} $$
The denominator is clearly real, and the imaginary part of the numerator is
$$ (ax+b)(-cy)+ay(cx+d) = y(ad-bc)=y, $$
which is positive if and only if $y$ is.

For the second part, it is clear that the orbit of $1$ is contained in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, since the coefficients of the transformation are real.

Next, it is also clear that
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
is in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$; this is equivalent to $1/(1-z)$, which clearly maps $1$ to $\infty$. Finally, for any real number $\alpha$, the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \alpha-1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
is also in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, and corresponds to the translation $z \mapsto z+(\alpha-1)$, which obviously maps $1$ to $\alpha$. Hence the orbit is the whole of the $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I needed to multiply by some clever "1" but could not for the life of me find it so I really appreciate your insight,

Comment: @Groupsn'Stuff It's worth remembering: it's a standard trick in complex numbers. It's basically the same thing as rationalising a surd in the denominator by multiplying by the denominator with the sign of the square root term changed.